# Is Stack Overflow a secure site? Why is Google Chrome showing a virus icon?

Tags: discussion, google-chrome, security

Is it only with me or also with others?

When I visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask:

[image]
[image]

I see Google Chrome is showing a virus icon and I was scared. Am I getting any exploits when that icon is shown by any sites now? Is it a new exploit of Google Chrome when that is shown?

How can I remove that icon? Does it has to be in Google Chrome or need to be fixed from the site I am visiting?

Comment: This belongs on meta.  Look in the network panel as indicated for what is being loaded over HTTP (and causing the symptom you see)

Comment: There's no "virus" icon in the images you've posted. As James Monger explained below, there's nothing malicious or particularly dangerous about the page. It just isn't fully loading over HTTPS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not insecure - it simply has some images which are loaded over HTTP rather than HTTPS.

The resources loaded over HTTP are your images.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwIXQ.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX026.png

Comment: Nice, now i learned it. But many users who do not have IT background they will think there trusted sites are not anymore trusted or spreading Virus. should Google Chrome not remove this feature to annoy the innocent user experience.

Comment: @YumYumYum The message isn't saying that it's not trusted, just that some resources aren't loaded via HTTPS. Please accept my answer if I helped you :)

Comment: @YumYumYum It is an `i` in a circle.  I've never known that to be a virus symbol, but rather an information symbol.

Comment: @YumYumYum well, Google are pushing for everyone to adopt https, which is not a bad idea overall. They seem willing to risk this kind of misunderstanding for the cause. SO are working hard to get everything on https - it’s just a matter of time that the symbol will disappear. It’s a task of epic proportions, though.

Comment: @Pekka: WOW. Sir you gave the very great answer. Google is actually playing all this. because of there core business related to internet and the more https they have safer for them.

Comment: @Yum not sure whether there’s a lot of direct benefit for them as a company (although consumers being able to trust Internet communications more is certainly also good for them in the long run.) See https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Google-pushing-SSL-by-rewarding-all-HTTPS-sites-with-better-search-rankings for opinions